# How to delete punctuation and number from element in the list?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a list with many nams of columns that i work with for my project.

my list is like this:

```
list_colunm = ['solar [W].1', 'Wind [W].02', 'Caz [W].33']
```

(and other elements it's a long list).

if you can help me with same methods to delete .1 .02 and .33

Comment: 1. Please don't shout. 2. This is not a coding service, show your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Standard Python:

```
list_column = ['solar [W].1', 'Wind [W].02', 'Caz [W].33']
list_shortnames = [x.rsplit('.')[0] for x in list_column]
```

**Output:**

```
['solar [W]', 'Wind [W]', 'Caz [W]']
```

### Pandas:

The most simple way is using [`rename()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) with a dict as a map.

```
import pandas as pd

mapping = {"solar [W].1": "solar [W]", "Wind [W].02": "Wind [W]", "Caz [W].33": "Caz [W]"}
df.rename(mapping, inplace=True, axis='columns')
```

More flexible alternative (@mozway):

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.rsplit('.', n=1)[0])
```

**Output:**

```
   solar [W]  Wind [W]  Caz [W]
0          1         2        3
```

Comment: don't use `map` as a variable name, it's an innocent useful python builtin that doesn't deserve to be shadowed ;)

Comment: Will edit. Thanks mozway for your great contributions like this!

Comment: `df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.rsplit('.', n=1)[0])`

Comment: Thanks for your inswer. my liste change automaticly from an excel file for exmeple same time my liste: list_colunm = ['solar.21',  'Headcoal.5, 'nucleaur.43'] and other time list_colunm = ['solar [W].1', 'Wind [W].02', 'Caz [W].33']

Comment: @MohamedJabbour I edited the answer. Thought you were operating on a pandas df due to the tags and the naming. Let me know, if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: @KarelZe Think yous so much, it's work, that what i look for

Comment: @mozway and thank you also for your contribution